# Захват видео с камеры

Tags: c++, linux, видео, opencv

Использую функцию `opencv - cvCreateCameraCapture(int)` для получение подключенной камеры.
Функция эта на линуксе всегда возвращает 0. Камера: веб камера, ноутбук HP. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, это поможет: [Захват с `web`-камеры с `OpenCV` под `Linux`](http://technhard.blogspot.ru/2013/02/web-opencv-linux.html)